# ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground subscription fail

Tags: express, graphql, apollo-server

I am trying to create simple graphQl server using apollo.
I followed Apollo's subscription example and it worked fine.

Now, I have to use apollo's playground, not the sandbox.

So I've added the `ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground` plugin to the `AolloServer` when building it.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  plugins: [
    ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground(),
```

but now I can't use subscriptions. it send me this error: `{ "error": "Could not connect to websocket endpoint ws://localhost:4000/graphql. Please check if the endpoint url is correct." }`

this is my full code:

```
import { ApolloServer } from "@apollo/server";
import { expressMiddleware } from "@apollo/server/express4";
import { createServer } from "http";
import express from "express";
import { makeExecutableSchema } from "@graphql-tools/schema";
import { WebSocketServer } from "ws";
import { useServer } from "graphql-ws/lib/use/ws";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import { PubSub } from "graphql-subscriptions";
import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground } from "@apollo/server-plugin-landing-page-graphql-playground";
const pubSub = new PubSub();

const typeDefs = `#graphql
  # Comments in GraphQL strings (such as this one) start with the hash (#) symbol.

  # This "Book" type defines the queryable fields for every book in our data source.
  type Book {
    title: String
    author: String
  }

  # The "Query" type is special: it lists all of the available queries that
  # clients can execute, along with the return type for each. In this
  # case, the "books" query returns an array of zero or more Books (defined above).
  type Query {
    books: [Book]
  }

  type Subscription{
    addBook: String
  }
`;

const books = [
  {
    title: "The Awakening",
    author: "Kate Chopin",
  },
  {
    title: "City of Glass",
    author: "Paul Auster",
  },
];

// Resolvers define how to fetch the types defined in your schema.
// This resolver retrieves books from the "books" array above.
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    books: () => {
      pubSub.publish("TEST", { addBook: "testing" });
      return books;
    },
  },
  Subscription: {
    addBook: {
      subscribe: () => pubSub.asyncIterator("TEST"),
    },
  },
};

// Create the schema, which will be used separately by ApolloServer and
// the WebSocket server.
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });

// Create an Express app and HTTP server; we will attach both the WebSocket
// server and the ApolloServer to this HTTP server.
const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);

// Create our WebSocket server using the HTTP server we just set up.
const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
  server: httpServer,
  path: "/graphql",
});
// Save the returned server's info so we can shutdown this server later
const serverCleanup = useServer({ schema }, wsServer);

// Set up ApolloServer.
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  plugins: [
    ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground(),
    // Proper shutdown for the WebSocket server.
    {
      async serverWillStart() {
        return {
          async drainServer() {
            await serverCleanup.dispose();
          },
        };
      },
    },
  ],
});

await server.start();
app.use(
  "/graphql",
  cors<cors.CorsRequest>(),
  bodyParser.json(),
  expressMiddleware(server)
);

const PORT = 4000;
// Now that our HTTP server is fully set up, we can listen to it.
httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is now running on http://localhost:${PORT}/graphql`);
});
```

When I don't use the plugin the subscriptions works. but I need it to work with the plugin.

Comment: Have you ever figured this out?

Comment: they said I should not use this plugin because it deprecated.
in the end I switched to graphql yoga that has built in offline option